# How do can i search for filenames in a directory using powershell?

Tags: powershell, find, powershell-ise, file-search

I need to search for filename '2018_reports.txt' in a directory '\\Save\' and its sub-directories '\\Save\2017\, \\Save\2018\'.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I have been able to check if the file exists if i place in the full path, however i need it to search the sub-directories too and return the full path.

My goal is to search for a fileName in the directory \Save and its sub directories and then return a msg saying 'Found with FullPATH' or 'NOT FOUND'.

Here is what i have so far

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\save -Filter 2018_reports.txt -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

Im am not able to return a msg saying the file is found. It is also not returning the full path.

Comment: A simple way is to store your command in a variable. Then use an if statement to see if there are any values: `if ($results) { "Found with $($results.Fullname)" }; else { "NOT FOUND" }`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to select matching object names with a wgere, and the return full path.

You alsi need to specify the full pathe to "\Save\" (unless \save is a share path, might be since it starts with \  ..? )

Eg:

.

```
        $(Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\save' -Recurse | ? {$_.name -match "2018_reports.txt" } ).FullName
```